# MongoDB - set replication to DocumentDB

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-documentdb

We're setting up a local MongoDB cluster - Locally, we'll have one primary and one node, and we want to have another node in AWS. Is it possible to have that node as the DocumentDB service instead of an EC2 instace?

Also, I know I must have an odd number of total nodes, is it possible to first add one node and then add another one?
Thanks ahaed.

Comment: No, it is not required to have an odd number of total nodes. However, when you have an even number and half of the nodes go down, then the replica set has no primary node, i.e. you cannot write anything because you have no **majority**. Either deploy an odd number or an [arbiter node](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/index.html) to get rid of this drawback.

Comment: If I have two nodes (1 primary and 1 secondary), and the primary goes down, isn't the secondary going to be the majority? Can't it vote for itself to become the primary?

Comment: No, one out of two is not the majority. For this you need an arbiter.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I know I must have an odd number of total nodes

In a MongoDB replica set, you can have any number of nodes you like. It is possible to have a 2-node replica set, although it's not very practically useful since unavailability of a single node (e.g. a restart for maintenance) would make the whole deployment unavailable for writes. A 4-node replica set is a feasible construction if you wanted an additional replica somewhere (e.g. for geographically close querying from a secondary, or for analytics querying), though if you are simply doing this for redundancy you should probably stick with the standard 3-node configuration and configure proper backups.

> Is it possible to first add one node and then add another one?

You can reconfigure a replica set at any time.

> Is it possible to have that node as the DocumentDB service instead of an EC2 instace?

Unlikely. DocumentDB is not MongoDB. DocumentDB *pretends* to be like a MongoDB but it 1) pretends to be an *old version* of MongoDB, 2) even then many features don't work, and 3) it's not anywhere near the same architecture as MongoDB under the hood. So when you ask a genuine MongoDB database to work with a DocumentDB node, this will probably not work.

This assumes you can even configure DocumentDB in the required manner - I suspect this won't be possible to begin with.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Two things. 1 - If I have two nodes (1 primary and 1 secondary), and the primary goes down, isn't the secondary going to be the majority? Can't it vote for itself to become the primary? 2 - Do I need to restart the primary if I add a node to the cluster?

Comment: Primary requires majority of nodes to be operating. The majority in a 2 node deployment is 2 nodes. Any single node being unavailable means you can't have a primary. No restarts are needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only trying to replicate the data to DocumentDB, Database Migration Service is a good tool for the job: https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

But like others have said, this will be a separate cluster from your MongodDB setup.